# Change an existing label name in tree view VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have this treeView with lets say items like so:

[image]

is there a way to make a right click (or something like that) option for me to be able to rename the let's say, bb label so it would open a typing window like that?

[image]

I can't find anything like that, or at least how it should be called so I can google it better.

Comment: Use a `WebviewView` and use any JS framework you like and implement it yourself

Comment: So I cannot use a Treeview? Is it possible to make a webview look like this?

Comment: you can make the `WebviewView` as fancy as you like and what HTML allows, maybe you can even use SVG and Canvas and D3.js

Answer (score 0):

The standard vscode treeview provider does not support inline editing (nor any styling other than an icon). You have to implement an own solution using HTML/CSS and place it in a webview (as rioV8 suggested).